# Как работает буферизации видео в html5 теге video

Tags: html5, http, видео, buffer

Когда видео воспроизводится с помощью тега video, то оно загружается с запасом(обгоняя время воспроизведения).
Вероятно это определяется заголовком запроса:

```
range: bytes=начало-конец
```

или заголовками ответа:

```
 Content-Length: размер 
 Content-Range: bytes начало-конец/размер файла
```

Как выбирается размер буфера, и как сервер понимает какую часть отдавать для буферизации, и что пора отдачу прекратить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, как Вы и написали это определяестя передачей на сервер:

```
range: bytes=начало-конец
```

Размер буфера определяется на клиенте в коде самого плеера, вероятно исходя из скорости соединения, разумеется это не видно для пользователя (нужно найти и посмотреть [исходники](https://github.com/chromium/chromium) тега `video`)

**Как это обрабатывается на сервере:**

- На сервере в обработчике запроса (путь к видео) проверяется есть ли `range`
- Если есть то разбивается на начало и конец по `-`
- Высчитывается размер чанка (куска видео для отправки)
- Открывается файл как стрим
- Заполняются заголовки с информацией о размерах
- передается видео через `pipe`

**Вот пример из реального кода:**

```
const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : fileSize-1
const chunksize = (end-start) + 1
const file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end})
const headers = {
  'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
  'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
  'Content-Length': chunksize,
  'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
}
res.writeHead(206, headers)
file.pipe(res)
```

Сервер в праве сам решать на основе дополнительных знаний (если у него есть информация о заряде телефона и т.п.) или собственной загруженности как он будет передавать данные.

вот пример передачи по 100КБ (`const end =  start + 100000` разумеется нужны еще проверки диапазона)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление:**

Хотя, мой ответ уже на данный момент был принят, я считаю нужным, как и обещал при наличии информации опубликовать ее. К сожалению объем исходников слишком велик для моих технических возможностей, однако путем беглого исследования мне удалось выяснить что `Chromium` в своей разработке ссылается на спецификацию `whatwg.org` а затем не составило большого труда обнаружить алгоритм принятия решения о буферизации, я добавлю ссылку на этот момент([resource fetch algorith](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#concept-media-load-resource)) думаю не составит труда сделать перевод, там не так много текста.

Comment: Поясните мне пож. тогда еще такой момент, который меня смутил и я подумал что не правильно понимаю как это все происходит. Наблюдал на сайтах: файл видео скажем 1Гб причем заголовок запроса такого вида   range: bytes=3342336-   а ответ говорит что отдам мол весь файл до конца Content-Range: bytes 3342336-1000000000/1000000000 . Но видео стоит на паузе и, загрузив впрок, скажем 10Мб дальше подгрузка не идет. А как только воспроизведение видео приближается к концу подгруженного, то загрузка возобновляется. Как сервер понимает что пора отдать еще информации в таком случае?

Comment: Посмотрел что сумбурно написал. Смотрю это все я на вкладке сеть(network) в браузере и дополнительно подгружается информация без прерывания полоски, которыми отображаются запросы. Т.е. вроде как не отправил новых заголовков, а сервер понял что нужно еще послать инфы. Как он это понял?  Ответ ниже по OSI или как?

Comment: Видел где-то что много факторов учитывается для вычисления размера буфера вплоть до, на пример заряда батареи и в таком духе(информация не надежная). Но не смог найти точного описания что да как. Может любознательность припрет и раскурю исходники. Ну или придет кто-то кто знает точно что и как считается...

Comment: по факту если второе значение не передается, то принимается что считывание идет до конца, это видно и в приведенном мной коде `fileSize-1` т.е. через pipе создается соединение которое не рвется а постепенно по мере необходимости подкачивает файл, если не перепрыгивать по видео то такой запрос будет 1 если перепрыгивать то количество будет равно количеству прыжков

Comment: дополнил ответ на основе приведенного вами фактора - `заряда батареи`, их действительно может быть много в том числе загруженность самого сервера, так же хотелось бы понимать предпосылку Вашего вопроса, для того чтобы знать как лучше ответить на него.

Comment: Я имел ввиду определение буфера на клиенте по зарядке, но разумеется и сервер может всю информацию принимать во внимание. Предпосылками было непонимание почему у меня при раздаче пролагивает видео. Но с этим уже разобрался сам(там банально все оказалось). Поэтому предпосылками можно считать любознательность, ну и желание чтобы была информация про это в одном месте для сообщества. Принимаю ответ, но если это прочтет кто-то, кто знает как конкретно рассчитывается буфер на клиенте напишите пож.

Comment: возможно, я скоро загляну в исходники поэтому если будут дополнения я обязательно добавлю в ответ

Comment: @Hertz, я обновил ответ, думаю это то что Вы искали, к сожалению на данный момент больше дополнить нечем.